# Installing nodeJs in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Hi I am trying to install nodejs in ubuntu 14 but getting following error.

```
 E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
    debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
    Extracting templates from packages: 62%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
    debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
    Extracting templates from packages: 100%
    dpkg: cannot scan updates directory `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/': No such file or directory
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

when trying to installing with software updated I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 300, in _process_transaction
    not self.is_dpkg_journal_clean()):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1111, in is_dpkg_journal_clean
    for dentry in os.listdir(status_updates):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/'
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174252/1100019

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem previously, I removed any variables equivalent to zero and it solved it, perhaps try that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Node.js-maintained repositories to your Ubuntu package source list with this command:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -`

Then install Node.js with apt-get:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Optionally we can create a symbolic link for node (for reasons mentioned earlier):

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Using this install option, we end up with newer versions of Node.js and npm:

```
$ node -v

$ npm -v
```

to check `node` version and `npm` version

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing nvm (node version manager)
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

it allows you to install and use ANY node version, and this may be way better, because ubuntu is bound to one specific version. In web development, every project is prepared using dofferen node, so switching it might be necessary